# `Mojo::Log` how to log to file and to stderr?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have a small `Mojolicious` application that uses a `Mojo::Log` logger. Something like the following:

```perl
my $log = Mojo::Log->new(path => 'app.log', level => 'trace');
$log->color(1);

get '/' => sub ($c) {
  $c->log->warn('Foo');
  $c->render(text => 'foo', status => 200);
}
```

What I expected was that I would get logs in stderr and/or stdout as well as logs to the file. Unfortunately this isn't the case. How can I have these logs show up in the applications stderr as well as the `app.log` file?

Comment: Since you've seen the source, it's Mojo::Log is obviously not designed for this. /// I expected `flock` to silently fail if you passed an IO::Tee object. But you say it warns. In that case, your options are (even more) limited. 1) Use a custom sublcass Mojo::Log that replaces `append`. 2) Or create a child task (thread or process) that reads from a pipe and outputs what it reads to two handles. The writer end of the pipe is passed to Mojo::Log.

Comment: Maybe you should simply run `tail -f app.log`...

Comment: @ikegami, Yeah I'm considering `tail -f` but I will have some listeners listening to the stderr of the process so I may have to re-think my approach.

Comment: The first sentence was supposed to be: "Since you've seen its source, you obviously know Mojo::Log wasn't designed for this."

Comment: @ikegami, I think I found a way around this using a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can use something like this (date stuff extracted from the `Mojo::Log` source):

```perl
my $log = Mojo::Log->new(path => 'app.log', level => 'trace');

$log->on(message => sub ($l, $level, @lines) {
    my $time = time;
    my ($s, $m, $h, $day, $month, $year) = localtime time;
    $time = sprintf('%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%08.5f', $year + 1900, $month + 1, $day, $h, $m,
                    "$s." . ((split '.', $time)[1] // 0));
    my $log_to_print = '[' . $time . '] ' . '[' . $level . '] ' . join(' ', @lines);
    if ($level eq 'trace' || $level eq 'info') {
        say $log_to_print;
    } else {
        print \*STDERR, $log_to_print . "\n";
    }
});
```

To forward a simplified log to `STDERR` or `STDOUT`, depending on the type. While it also writes logs to the file provided in `path =>` when creating the logger.